# Properties of an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a novice in nodejs and javascript .I am learning nodejs. I have a doubt here . I came across a node js code , which I was unable to understand :

```
 jumble = {} ;

 jumble.debug = false;

 jumble.start = function (guid, callback) {

 }
```

I am still wondering , what does jumble.start do when its just an empty array, any help /links would be appreciated Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no arrays here.

`jumble = {} ;` creates a object and assigns it to `jumble`

`jumble.debug = false` creates a property called `debug` on the object and assigns the value `false` to it.

`jumble.start = function (guid, callback) {}` creates a property called `start` on the object and assigns a function to it.

You could call that function with `jumble.start(1,2)`, but it wouldn't do anything since the function doesn't have anything between `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `node.js` but, I know it is similar to `javascript`.

So, first of all, `jumble` is an object and not an array, as you think it is.

`debug` is a property of `jumble` object which has been assigned the value of `false`.

`start` is a function of `jumble` object which is obviously empty as it does nothing when called by doing `jumble.start(3,4)`.